# How do I "do stuff" at the end of this crazy jQuery animation loop without errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-animate, jquery-masonry

I am trying to "do some stuff" at the end of this crazy animation loop... The alert I have commented out at the end of the animation works great... However, what I really need it to do is remove/hide the closest div with a class of .item (something like this)

```
    var jremove = $(this).closest('.item').hide();
        $container.masonry('remove', jremove );

        //Then trigger a reload function for masonry
        reloadMasonry();   // not working yet
```

When I try do do anything but alert a simple message I get an error like this:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'closest'
```

You can see it at the bottom of the animation below:

```
 jQuery(function ($) {

    $("body").on("click", ".clip_it", function () {
        if ($(this).parent().find(".clip_it").length<1){
            $(this).after('<a class="clip_it" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="">CLIP IT!</a><img src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v29/wormholes201/animated-scissors.gif" class="ToBeAnimated">');
    }

    animationLoop($(this).closest(".item-inner").eq(0),$(this).parent().find(".ToBeAnimated").eq(0));
  });
});
  function animationLoop(ctx,ctx2) {
    ctx2.fadeIn();
     ctx2.css({
      top: (0 - parseInt(ctx2.height()) / 2),
       left: (0 - parseInt(ctx2.width()) / 2),
       position:"absolute",
       "z-index":800
    }).rotate(270);
    ctx2.animate({
      top: ctx.height() - ctx2.height() / 2
    }, 1000, function () {
      ctx2.animate({
        rotate: "180deg"
       }, 1000, function () {
         ctx2.animate({
          left: ctx.width() - ctx2.width() / 2
        }, 1000, function () {
           ctx2.animate({
             rotate: "90deg"
           }, function () {
             ctx2.animate({
               top: 0-ctx2.height() / 2
             }, 1000, function () {
              ctx2.animate({
                rotate: "0deg"
              }, function () {
                ctx2.animate({
                  left: (0 - parseInt(ctx2.width()) / 2)
                }, 1000, function () {
                  setTimeout(animationLoop(ctx,ctx2), 1000);

                //I want to remove the coupon (.item) & reload masonry here 
                // TEST ALERT WORKS = alert("animation complete");

                    var jremove = $(this).closest('.item').hide();
                    $container.masonry('remove', jremove );

                    reloadMasonry();
                    return false;
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
}
```

I am open to other suggestions if you think there is a better way? THANKS FOR HELPING!

Comment: Just a comment : when you have such a cascade at the end of your code you're sure you have a design problem. You can't maintain this.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you have a look at the [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) from jQuery. You can  easily clean up this mess.

Comment: Yikes... Not exactly the answers I was hoping for... It's taken me quite a while to get to this point :-/  I will look into the deferred object stuff for cleaning it up though... but If anyone can help I still would like to figure out a fix for now????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'closest'`

The problem is that `$` *outside* of your ready handler (the function you're passing into `jQuery(function($) { ... });`) is not pointing to jQuery, it's pointing to something else (my guess would be Prototype or MooTools). So `$(this)` returns an `HTMLImageElement` (probably enhanced by Prototype or MooTools) rather than a jQuery object, and so it has no `closest` function.

Either move the `animationLoop` function *into* your ready handler (so it sees the `$` that jQuery passes into the ready handler instead of the global), or use `jQuery` instead of `$` in that function.